# How can I find out if an arraylist is missing one and only one element from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a String arraylist called 'hand' that takes random elements from 3 different String arrays, PEOPLE, WEAPONS AND ROOMS. Is there any way I can determine if the arraylist has all but one element from each category? So if 'hand' contains 8 of the 9 Strings in the String array ROOMS, it will return the string that it doesn't have for that array? This method should only apply if 'hand' is missing EXACTLY 1 element from the specified array. If it's missing more than one element from a specified array, it shouldn't do anything.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public List<String> hand = new ArrayList<String>();

public final static String[] PEOPLE = new String[] {
        "Miss. Scarlet",
        "Mrs. Peacock",
        "Colonel Mustard",
        "Professor Plum",
        "Mrs. White",
        "Mr. Green"
    };

public final static String[] WEAPONS = new String[] {
        "Wrench",
        "Candlestick",
        "Pipe",
        "Rope",
        "Revolver",
        "Knife"
    };

public final static String[] ROOMS = new String[] {
        "Library",
        "Kitchen",
        "Study",
        "Conservatory",
        "Ballroom",
        "Lounge",
        "Hall",
        "Billiard Room",
        "Dining Room"
    };

public Main() {
    hand.add("Library");
    hand.add("Lounge");
    hand.add("Wrench");
    hand.add("Miss. Scarlet");
    hand.add("Mrs. Peacock");
    hand.add("Colonel Mustard");
    hand.add("Professor Plum");
    hand.add("Mrs. White");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
}
}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are looking for. Can you provide several examples with input and expected output

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework, there are much better ways to store your data points than in 3 separate String arrays to make solving your task a lot easier.

Comment: Check the size... If it is size minus one, then check which one is missing and do nothing otherwise...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if different arraylists each contain the same string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496735/how-to-check-if-different-arraylists-each-contain-the-same-string)

Comment: UserF40 This isn't my homework. I'm not even a student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare a method that takes two parameters : the constant list and your hand and that will return a `String` : the missing `String` element in your hand if it is the last one missing or else `null`.
2. Call this method three times by passing at each time your hand and one of the three constant lists.

That's all.
In code it could give :

```
public String findLastMissingElement(String[] constants, List<String> hand){
   String missingElement = null;
   for (String constant : constants){

       if (!hand.contains(constant) && missingElement==null){ 
          missingElement = constant;
       }
       else if (!hand.contains(constant)){ 
         return null;
       }
   }
   return missingElement;
}
```

And you could call it in this way :

```
String missingPeople = findLastMissingElement(PEOPLE, hand);
String missingWeapon = findLastMissingElement(WEAPONS, hand);
String missingRoom = findLastMissingElement(ROOMS, hand);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're looking for: use `removeAll()` method on a `List`.
So, convert your arrays to `List` with `Arrays.asList(..)`.
Than `removeAll` hands collection from each of your former arrays. If the size of the remaining List is 1 - this is what you are looking for.

```
List<String> peoples = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(PEOPLE));
peoples.removeAll(hands);
if (peoples.size() == 1)
{
    // here your hands List contained all items from PEOPLE, except 1
}
```

Comment: Thread [main] (Suspended (exception UnsupportedOperationException)) 
 Arrays$ArrayList<E>(AbstractList<E>).remove(int) line: not available 
 AbstractList$Itr.remove() line: not available 
 Arrays$ArrayList<E>(AbstractCollection<E>).removeAll(Collection<?>) line: not available 
 Main.check() line: 53 
 Main.<init>() line: 48 
 Main.main(String[]) line: 69

Comment: Use another `ArrayList` creation: `List<String> peoples = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(PEOPLE));`